# Subclass Variables are Undefined - js

Tags: javascript, class, subclass

I am programming a game and am having trouble with variables and inheritance, whenever I try to access them in the inherited class they come up as `undefined`. I have tried using `super` to help with the problem but that has not worked, this may be because I am relatively new to JavaScript.

The variables work in the base class but do not work in the subclass. 
[This is the inherited class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tckC7.png)
This is the [Base Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDpcq.png).

Just to clarify the question I am asking why the variables come up as undefined in the subclass but not in the base class and how I can fix this. Thanks!

The code is clearer in the pictures.

```js
class charachter {

    constructor(xPos, yPos) {
        this.rightVelocity = 0;
        this.leftVelocity = 0;
        this.upVelocity = 0;
        this.downVelocity = 0;
        this.xyCordsRaw = [xPos, yPos];
        this.xyCordsBlock = [Math.round(this.xyCordsRaw[0] / 50),
            Math.round(this.xyCordsRaw[1] / 100)
        ]
    }

    updateCharachter() {
        ctx.drawImage(charachterRight, this.xyCordsRaw[0],
            this.xyCordsRaw[1])
    }

    findTileStandingOnType() {
        return
        solidObjects.includes(biome[this.xyCordsBlock[1] + 1][this.xyCordsBlock[0]])
    }

    isOnTheGround() {
        return this.findTileStandingOnType() == true &&
            this.xyCordsRaw[1] == (this.xyCordsBlock[1] * 100) + 25
    }

    isTileAbove() {
        return solidObjects.includes(biome[this.xyCordsBlock[1] - 1]
            [this.xyCordsBlock[0]])
    }

    isTouchingTileAbove() {
        return this.isTileAbove() == true && this.xyCordsBlock[1] * 100 == this.xyCordsRaw[1]
    }

    isWallLeft() {
        return solidObjects.includes(biome[this.xyCordsBlock[1]][this.xyCordsBlock[0] - 1])
    }

    isWallRight() {
        return solidObjects.includes(biome[this.xyCordsBlock[1]][this.xyCordsBlock[0] + 1])
    }

    isTouchingWallRight() {
        return this.isWallRight() == true && this.xyCordsBlock[0] * 50 == this.xyCordsRaw[0]
    }

    isTouchingWallLeft() {
        return this.isWallLeft() == true && this.xyCordsBlock[0] * 50 == this.xyCordsRaw[0]
    }
}

class playerChar extends charachter {

    constructor(xPos, yPos, leftVelocity, rightVelocity, upVelocity, downVelocity, xyCordsRaw, xyCordsBlock) {
        super(xPos, yPos, leftVelocity, rightVelocity, upVelocity, downVelocity, xyCordsRaw, xyCordsBlock);
        document.addEventListener('keydown', this.takeInput);
    }

    takeInput(e) {
        if (e.code == 'KeyA') {
            console.log(this.leftVelocity);
        }
        if (e.code == 'KeyW') {
            console.log("The letter W was pressed");
        }
        if (e.code == 'KeyD') {
            console.log(this.xyCordsRaw);
        }
    }
}

var player = new playerChar(150, 325);
```

Comment: Post code, not pictures of code.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem that presents itself is the use of `this` in event listeners.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', this.takeInput);
```

passes a reference to the `takeInput` function object when calling `addEventListener`, and because it's an event handler of `document`, `takeInput` will have a `this` value of `document` when called. Try

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', this.takeInput.bind(this));
```

to begin with to see what difference it makes.

---

The next error to correct is to the line feed after `return` in

```
findTileStandingOnType(){
return 
solidObjects.includes(biome[this.xyCordsBlock[1]
```

This should be

```
findTileStandingOnType(){
return solidObjects.includes(biome[this.xyCordsBlock[1] + 1][this.xyCordsBlock[0]])}
```

Return statements without a semi-colon separator only continue on the next line if it would be a syntax error if they didn't. That is not the 
case here.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the array 'this.xyCordsRaw    = [xPos, yPos];' in the base class constructor still comes up as undefined. All the other variables, which were preassigned like 'this.downVelocity  = 0;' (also in the base class) now work in the subclass.

Comment: Unable to reproduce `undefined` for 'this.xyCordsRaw` -  pressing 'd' logs `Array [150, 325]` on the console as expected.